# Solving systems of linear equations with an unknown 'a' using matrices and elementary row operations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

Came across this one the other day... while I can narrow 'a' down I can't seem to find an exact/ optimised figure. For example 'a' cannot equal 1/3, 'a' must be less than 0.5...

Anyway, here's the problem. I've got a 3x3 matrix by a 3x1 which equates to a 3x1.

{0.6, 0.2, a},{0.4, 0.3, a},{0.0, 0.5, 1-2a}.{x, y, z} = {1360, 1260, 2000}

Would appreciate any help available,

Kind regards,

1AM35

Comment: these are all column vectors?

Comment: the last two are, but the first is a square

Comment: I know the first three represent a square matrix, but are the vectors column vectors or row vectors?  A matrix is made up of column vectors.  Is the top row of the square .6 .2 a or is that the first column of the square?

Comment: Ahh yep, sorry. They're row vectors. (So the top row is .6 .2 a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: do Gaussian Elimination or Row-Reduced-Echelon-Form (RREF). Note that I changed all the decimals to fractions to get exact results. You will end up with the identity matrix on the left of your augmented matrix, with:

- $z = -\dfrac{940}{3a - 1}$
- $y = \dfrac{40(206 a - 53)}{3a -1}$
- $x = \dfrac{20(281a-78)}{3a-1}$

From this you can see that $a \ne \dfrac{1}{3}$, otherwise $a$ is a "free variable" that you can make anything you like.

You effectively found the inverse of the matrix on the LHS times the column vector on the RHS.

Comment: There was something that I missed - sometimes you just need to see someone else lay it out before you can fit the rest of the puzzle. Thank you very much.

Comment: @1AM35: We all have those moments, no problem, happy to help! Regards

Comment: Deserves another TU! (Nice feedback here, as well!) +1